# My loop for changing background-color doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to make a loop that every 8 seconds change my div ("items") background-color to white for 1s, and then back to black.

```js
let x;

function changeColor() {
  x = setInterval(xyz, 1000);
}

function xyz() {
  let elem = document.getElementsByClassName("items");
  if (elem[0].style.backgroundColor == 'black') {
    elem[0].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  } else {
    elem[0].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  }
}

function stopchangeColor() {
  clearInterval(x);
}
```

```html
<div class="items" style="background-color: black;"></div>
```

Comment: @Aalexander Your snippet doesn't do anything (other than "showing" an empty div)

Comment: @Andreas you can better take a look at it and showing nothing gives also some informations.

Comment: @Aalexander Without a call for `changeColor()` this snippet doesn't add anything useful compared to the code block it was before, which makes this an unnecessary edit.

Comment: @Andreas this was exactly what I mean. Maybe the snippet show some people that the call is missing. No output can also give informations about the behavior

Comment: @Andreas another question, do you think that it is less readable than before? If not then it is just a benefit to have the snippet. 1. Because you are able to let it run and validate what happens.(No output also gives you informations). 2. If people want to answer the question they can press the *Copy snippet to answer* button what is more comfortable than copy pasting the code and make a snippet. 3. At the first glance you can see the *HTML* and the *JS* section.
And there is no downside in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation :** the function `changeColor()` sets `setInterval` to call function `xyz()` once in every 8 seconds. Then, in function `xyz()`, the background color is changed to white. The `setTimeout` changes the background color to black just after one second.

```js
var x;

function changeColor() {
  x = setInterval(xyz, 8000);
}

function xyz() {
  let elem = document.getElementsByClassName("items");
  elem[0].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  setTimeout(()=>{
    elem[0].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  }, 1000);
}

function stopchangeColor() {
  clearInterval(x);
}


changeColor();
```

```css
.items {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items" style="background-color: black;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example the div was empty and no size set so nothing was showing.

You also need to start the timer as well as set a different timer depending on if it's black or white :)

```js
let x;

function xyz() {
  let elem = document.getElementsByClassName("items");
  if (elem[0].style.backgroundColor == 'black') {
    elem[0].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    clearInterval(x);
    x = setInterval(xyz, 1000);
  } else {
    elem[0].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    clearInterval(x);
    x = setInterval(xyz, 8000);
  }
}

function stopchangeColor() {
  clearInterval(x);
}

x = setInterval(xyz, 8000);
```

```css
.items {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items" style="background-color: black;"></div>
```

Comment: Your code is working perfectly, but you can do it in less lines, by using setTimeout function. Take a look at my answer :)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed :) Your solution is cleaner as well

Answer (score 0):

it seems to work...

```js
const elem = document.getElementsByClassName("items");

function xyz() {
  elem[0].style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff'
  setTimeout(() => {
    elem[0].style.backgroundColor = '#000000'
  }, 1000)
}
setInterval(() => xyz(), 8000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .items {
      background-color: black;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="items">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```